# Append rows to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to add python list to a csv file with this code:

```
RESULTS = ['aa','bb','cc']
resultFile = open("c:\\temp\\output4.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerows(RESULTS)
resultFile.flush()
```

but this code overwrites my previous file. how to enable appending?

Unfortunately I can't find any solution to do this using this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in append mode instead:

```
resultFile = open("c:\\temp\\output4.csv", 'ab')
```